# How to Inject @Alternative with CDI from WAR into JAR Module

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1, jpa-2.1

The `TheConverter` would like to use an injected `Config` produced by the `ConfigProducer`.
Where `ConfigProducer` is in the WAR but `TheConverter` and `Config` are in a jar.
Sadly it seems the `config` isn't injected leading to a `javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter` caused by a `NullPointerException` in `TheConverter`.

I'm using WildFly 8.1.0 which uses Weld to do CDI injection.

Am I trying to do something impossible or is this meant to work?

```
example.war
  - ConfigProducer.class
      @Produces Config
  - WEB-INF/beans.xml (empty <beans></beans>)
  - META-INF/persistence.xml
  - WEB-INF/lib/entities.jar
     - Config.class
     - TheConverter.class
         implements AttributeConverter
         @Inject Config <-- FAIL
     - TheEntity.class
     - META-INF/beans.xml (empty <beans></beans>)
     - META-INF/orm.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly your problem is. But it is definitively possible to use this Producer and injection point combination.

Also WildFly should warn you if there were problems during bean discovery...

Probably you can add some more explanation about your beans.xml's, the Producer class and the persistence.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your `beans.xml` in your WAR file needs to go in `WEB-INF`, not `META-INF`

Comment: Oops. I typed that wrong here, but it is in WEB-INF in my project.